# I am starting web-scraping with python and

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am just trying to pick a title of an item of a website and my code its ->

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://pauta.com.br/produto/31394"

headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"}

site = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')

#print(soup.prettify())

title = soup.find('h4', class_ = 'ng-binding')
print(title)
```

Why my output its "none" ?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. You are [expected to have tried to solve the problem yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users),  for example in this case by reading the documentation and by verifying your input (does *the HTML itself* - not anything created later by Javascript - contain the expected `<h4 class="ng-binding">` tag?). You should give your question a title that describes the problem, not half of an introductory sentence.

Comment: <h4 ng-show="escondeImagem" class="ng-binding">NOBREAK TS SHARA MINI 600VA/390W 4003 BIV/115</h4>

the code has this

Comment: Do you see this if you view source on the page (*do not* use inspect element etc.)? Because I don't. I don't see any `h4` tags at all, in fact. Keep in mind that as well as Javascript, content can be jammed into `iframe`s with source from a different URL.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel on view-source:https://pauta.com.br/produto/40277 I can't see this title

Comment: Right, so that's the problem. BeautifulSoup cannot give you HTML content that is dynamically loaded (unless you can figure out a URL for the AJAX request - better yet, see if the website offers a proper API) or externally referenced via an iframe (unless you use the URL for that iframe source). You will need to analyze how the site works.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't know how to do that, but thanks for your response! Happy with that.

Answer (score 1):

The site uses JavaScript to render the page (as stated in comments). You can simulate Ajax request to obtain the product information (all you need is product number):

```py
import json
import requests

product_number = 31394

url = f"https://api.pauta.com.br/ecommerce-web/api2/produto/{product_number}/0/0/XX/false/false"
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["proCodigo"], data["proDescricao"])
```

Prints:

```
31394 NOBREAK TS SHARA MINI 600VA/390W 4003 BIV/115
```